# How to change border radius of bootstrap modal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am unable to change the border radius of bootstrap modal.

```
.modal{
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px; 
}
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Can someone kindly add the `bootstrap 4` and `bootstrap 5` tags to this question since this issue is relevant with the current bootstrap versions as well?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

### BOOTSTRAP 3:

In Bootstrap 3, you need to apply the border radius to the **`.modal-content`** div element and not the **`.modal`** div element like this:

```
.modal-content  {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important; 
}
```

**N.B.** Remove the `!important` tags if your custom css is loaded **after** your bootstrap css.

---

### BOOTSTRAP 4 & BOOTSTRAP 5:

In Bootstrap 4 & Bootstrap 5, you can just add the **`rounded-0`** class name to your **`modal-content`** element (or to any other element) to set it's border radius to `0` like this:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content rounded-0">
        <!-- Your Modal content here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can just use `rounded-0` bootstrap class.

```html
<div class="modal-content rounded-0">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you're trying to style the wrong element.

According to [getbootstrap.com/javascript/#static-example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#static-example), you should style:

```
.modal-content
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following and success :

```
<div class="modal-content" style="background: transparent;">
                      <div class="modal-body" style="border-radius: 10px;">
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Bootstrap 4** Try the following:

```
.modal-content {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  -webkit-border: 0px !important;
  -moz-border: 0px !important;
  border: 0px !important;
}
```

**border-radius** removes the rounded corners while **border** removes all borders (left, right, top, bottom) around the modal.

Answer (score 0):

In order to overwrite a piece of CSS you could add the following to your custom CSS file, assuming this file loads after Bootstrap.

```
.modal{
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answers above and I got halfway there. After some inspection I realized that my particular instance had both a .modal-content portion as well as a .modal-dialog portion. So be careful that you don't have two borders on the same modal pop-up. After I removed the .modal-dialog border and adjusted the .modal-content, my modals look super slick!

```
.modal-content { 
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
}

.modal-dialog {
    border: 0px !important;
}
```

As the previous answers state, use the !important if your code appears before the bootstrap code.

Answer (score 0):

### Bootstrap >5.2

Setting the variable makes sure it is consistent app wide:

```
$modal-content-border-radius: 0;
```