# why am I not able to change my modal's border-radius despite of styling my modal-content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how can I change the border-radius property of my modal?
I've already checked this link but it didn't solve my issue:
[How to change border radius of bootstrap modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479233/how-to-change-border-radius-of-bootstrap-modal)

this is my code:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="MyPicLarge" role="MyPicLarge">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="MyImageSrc">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>

    <style>
    #MyPicLarge .modal-content {
        height: 550px;
        width: 420px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 50px!important;
    }
    </style>
```

if you pay attention, even by specifying `!important` in my css, it's still not working. I've given the style to my `.modal-content`. so basically it must work but the borders are still sharp while I want rounded corners.
I'm using bootstrap 3.
does anybody know what my mistake is?

Comment: I tried this code and it shows border-radius on all sides that you have specified

Comment: Please see/attach debugger style computation screenshot. Your CSS might be getting over-ride by another style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, you actually need to give the style `border-radius: 50px;` or any other arbitrary number to your `#MyPicLarge .modal-header` too. then you don't need to have CSS !important property. Something like this:

```
#MyPicLarge .modal-header {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

Pay attention that we're not gonna set the value for the lower left and right corners. We're gonna set them when styling `.modal-footer`. Something like this:

```
#MyPicLarge .modal-footer {
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

This is besides having the border-radius style for your `#MyPicLarge .modal-content`.

Then you can see that all of your 4 corners will be round in Bootstrap 3 Modals.

Just keep in mind that the border-radius value for `.modal-content` must be equal to the border-radius value of `.modal-header` and `.modal-footer`. For example if you choose `10px`, then don't change the number for the other one to cover the corners for you perfectly.

So, totally in the codes I have here, giving `border-radius` style only to my `.modal-content` wasn't enough and i had to give those two blocks of code I mentioned above to my project to fix this issue.